# what is the default value of char pointer or char variable

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char

Below is the code where I am trying to print default values/values of char variable & pointer. But Can not able to see it on console.Is it has default values or just not able to read ASCII range.?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c, *cp;

    printf("\nValue of char c:%c\n", c);
    printf("\nValue of char ptr:%c\n", *cp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since they are not initialized they can be anything.

Comment: The values are *"indeterminate"*. (variables with *automatic* storage type have indeterminate value if not initialized and in the alternative until a value is assigned)

Answer (score 2):

Surprise!! there is no "default" value here, you're venturing into undefined behavior.

To elaborate, if a variable is local scoped and automatic storage duration, unless initialized explicitly, the stored value is indeterminate. Using that further, causes undefined behavior.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate.[....]

- For the first case, where you have a `char` type, if in your case, which can have a trap representation, it'll lead to UB, otherwise, it'll be a random value.
- For the second case, where you have a `char *` type, the pointer holds indeterminate value, which is *invalid* in context of your program, so attempt to dereference the pointer surely invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

All `automatic` variables in C/C++ have undefined value if unintialized!

You are actually wandering into the dangerous region of 'Undefined Behavior' by using such uninitialized variables (all the more, by de-referencing the pointer).

Answer (score 1):

First of all C and C++ are very different languages with often very different semantics.

However, this is one case where both are quite similar (even though there are differences between the specifications): Uninitialized local ("automatic") non-static variables will have an *indeterminate* value.

In C++ using them in any way except to initialize them leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer almost doubly so.

Answer (score 1):

The *default value* would be the value assigned by *default initialization*, which is `0` for an integer type (like `char`) and a *nullpointer* for any pointer type. So, your code would already be wrong here:

```
printf("\nValue of char ptr:%c\n", *cp);
```

because the *nullpointer* can't be dereferenced, it points explicitly *nowhere*. Dereferencing it leads to **undefined behavior**.

But, as you define these variables with *automatic storage duration* (the default in function scope) -- **they don't get initialized at all** unless you do it yourself. So, their initial value is just *indeterminate*. This means your first line

```
printf("\nValue of char c:%c\n", c);
```

prints some *indeterminate value*. Whether this is **undefined behavior** as well depends on whether your `char` is by default signed or unsigned. A signed char is allowed to have *trap representations*, so you could attempt to print something here that isn't a valid representation of a `char` -> **undefined behavior**.

Dereferencing some "random" pointer is **undefined behavior** as well (and in practice very likely to crash your program).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, they are not **initialised!** assign a value to your variables.

**For example:**

```
char c = 's', *cp = %c;

printf("\nValue of char c:%c\n", c); 
printf("\nValue of char ptr:%c\n", *cp);
```

Comment: Assigning 'o' to a pointer will probably crash your application. `char *cp = &c;` would be better.

Comment: @JimFell you are right, I have `corrected`my answer